# Error after runtime upgrade to reduce `EPOCH_DURATION_IN_SLOTS` of `westend-local` relay chain

Tags: substrate, polkadot

I've got a `0.9.12` `westend-local` relay chain with 4 authorities Alice, Charlie, Bob and Dave. My goal is to do a runtime upgrade to reduce `EPOCH_DURATION_IN_SLOTS` to let's say 1 minute instead of 1 hour.
However I'm getting the following error `babe: Error with block built on 0x...: ClientImport("Unexpected epoch change")`
Is it possible to reduce this parameter without breaking the chain ? Still trying to make sense of the associated code https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/client/consensus/babe/src/lib.rs#L1500

Comment: The error message indeed indicates that you can't change this once launched, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible to change this without restarting the chain: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/b6a3ecc150040daa440637ac892265165f3450f6/frame/babe/src/lib.rs#L124-L128.